# How to normalize Integer variable to positive negative or zero with bit operations

Tags: swift, integer, normalization, bit

```
7 -> 1
0 -> 0
-7 -> -1
```

I've have code:

```
(x == 0 ? 0 : x / abs(x)) + 1
```

but is it possible to avoid division and make it faster?

Comment: `abs`, `division` and `addition` on integers are native processor instructions. They're very likely to be much faster than any kind of branching code. You'll have to benchmark and compare

Comment: First tests showed that the multilevel if else statement works about 4 time faster...

Comment: Use the unsafe division operator, and the unsafe add operator. That'll remove 2 branches

Comment: What is "unsafe division operator" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea was to use bit operations to avoid branching code or value conversion.
Haven't found how to do it with bit operations but apple already add this function

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/int/2886673-signum

```
signum()
Returns -1 if this value is negative and 1 if it’s positive; otherwise, 0.
```

so simple) raw test shows ~x100 faster implementation

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
(x == 0 ? 0 : (x < 0 ? -1 : 1))
```

Comment: Minor nitpick: it's much more likely a value is non-zero than zero (of course, that depends on the data set). So if performance is crucial, then you could do  `0 < x ? 1 : (x < 0 ? : -1 : 0)` or `0 > x ? 1 : (x < 0 ? : -1 : 0)`. The former would be better if positive numbers were expected to be the most frequency, and the latter would be better if negative numbers were expected to be the most frequent. In either case though, I suspect this branching would be slower than the branchless code OP is discontent about